# Fiddler shows data, controller is null

Tags: knockout.js

I've been trying to work this problem out for weeks...

This reports a valid JSON request to the controller but the controller reports null for the data.

```
function ViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.CurrentColors = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AddColors = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AllColors = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.save = function () 
    {
        SendData = ko.toJSON(AddColors);
        alert(SendData);

        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: '/EditColor/PostColors',
            data: SendData

        }).success(function (data) {

        });
    };
} 

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

controller data model:

```
public class AjaxColorList
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string bNotPermanent { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddler shows this: (which looks right)

```
[{"ID":"15","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":"1"},{"ID":"21","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":"1"}]
```

The following posts the exact same data, but my controller sees the data.  I'm not an expert when it comes to javascript yet (just learning now) so I'm not fully understanding what is happening.  After getting the second iteration to work; I can't get the document.ready to be recognized and other various issues.

```
$(function () {
    var baseModel = {
        // data
        addColors: ko.observableArray([{"ID":"15","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":"1"},{"ID":"21","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":"1"}]),
        postColors: function () {
            console.log(baseModel.addColors());
            $.ajax({
                url: '/EditColor/PostColors',
                contentType: "application/json",
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(baseModel.addColors()),
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("FAIL: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log("SUCCES");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(baseModel);
});
```

The fiddler data looks the same as above.

Can anyone shed any light on why the top code will not work?

Comment: ContentType vs. contentType. The parameter names are case sensitive! It correct one is **contentType**!

Comment: ah I had a good feeling about that; just changed, recompiled and tested.  Same thing...  Controller reports that data as null.

Comment: NEVERMIND! OMG This works!  I had to back out some other code that I was playing with trying to figure out the issue! THANK YOU! You don't know how long I've been struggling with this.  Can you "answer" the question so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is corrected above.  It was an issue with "contentType" being right cased. THANK YOU!